# Undefined variable Trying to get property of non-object elements class

Tags: php, class, element

I've some trouble with class in php

```
class one{
     public $value;
}
```

Call

```
$workone = new one();
```

Second Class

```
class two{
     function working(){
        $value = $workone->value;
     }
}
```

I'm getting this error:

> Undefined variable: workone in /xxx/xxxx/xxx on line x
>
> Trying to get property of non-object in /xxx/xxxx/xxx on line x

Comment: This is because the variable is out of scope!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would had done it.

By using dependency injection !

```
class one{
     public $value;
}
class two{
     private $workone;
     function __construct(One $workone){
        $this->workone = $workone;
     }
     function working(){
        $value = $this->workone->value;
     }
}

$workone = new one();
$worktwo = new two($workone);
$worktwo->working();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use global keyword. Use the code below

```
class two{ 
function working(){ 
global $workone;
$value = $workone->value; 
} 
}
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: It's bad practice to use `global`!

Comment: @Rizier123 I know.. but it can be used to do this

Comment: *I know* Then why do you propose this to OP?!

Comment: Because this can make the variable in the scope @Rizier123

Answer (score 0):

You can work with inheritence the property `$value` in class one will contain `myValue` if you implement beneath code.

```
class one {
  protected $value;
}

class two extends one {
  public function working($value){
     $this->value = $value;
  }
}

$classTwo = new two();
$classTwo->working('myValue');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read about scope! You're trying to access a variable that was defined outside the method `working` of the class `two` and this variable wasnt defined as a global variable.

But sometimes, declare a variable as global can bring to you more problems. So my advice is to pass the variable as an argument to your method `working`...

```
class two{
      function working($workone){
              $value = $workone->value;
      }
}
```

or define your $`workone` variable inside the method working if it matches your needs. More important than get a solution, is to understand a solution. Please, read more about scope:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php